# Here SDK mapLoader.getMapPackageAtCoordinate return true but I never get result on callback

Tags: android, kotlin, here-api

I am using Here SDK and everything looks fine with initialization but when I call:

```
val getMapPackageResult = mapLoader.getMapPackageAtCoordinate(GeoCoordinate(52.500556, 13.398889, 0.0))
```

to get maps packages to install, `MapPackageAtCoordinateListener` call back never get called!

It is not the same when I call `mapLoader.getMapPackages` with no GeoCoordination!

Could it be any limitation for my trial account from the back end?
Any suggestion?

---

**more details**

I am following this sample repo https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/map-downloader

```
val diskCacheRoot = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path}${File.separator}.isolated-here-maps"

MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot, HERE_MAP_ACTION)


mapLoader = MapLoader.getInstance()

mapLoader.addListener(object : MapLoader.Listener {

    override fun onProgress(i: Int) {
        Timber.i("onProgress $i")
    }

    override fun onInstallationSize(l: Long, l1: Long) {
        Timber.i("onInstallationSize")
    }

    override fun onGetMapPackagesComplete(mapPackage: MapPackage, resultCode: MapLoader.ResultCode) {
        Timber.i("onGetMapPackagesComplete name = " + mapPackage.englishTitle + " , resultCode = " + resultCode)
    }

    override fun onCheckForUpdateComplete(b: Boolean, s: String, s1: String, resultCode: MapLoader.ResultCode) {
        Timber.i("onCheckForUpdateComplete")
    }

    override fun onPerformMapDataUpdateComplete(mapPackage: MapPackage, resultCode: MapLoader.ResultCode) {
        Timber.i("onPerformMapDataUpdateComplete")
    }

    override fun onInstallMapPackagesComplete(mapPackage: MapPackage, resultCode: MapLoader.ResultCode) {
        Timber.i("onInstallMapPackagesComplete resultCode = $resultCode")
        if (resultCode == MapLoader.ResultCode.OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL) {
            Timber.i("onInstallMapPackagesComplete mapPackage = " + mapPackage.title)
        } else {
            listener.onError(NavigationException())
        }
    }

    override fun onUninstallMapPackagesComplete(mapPackage: MapPackage, resultCode: MapLoader.ResultCode) {
        Timber.i("onUninstallMapPackagesComplete")
    }
})

mapLoader.addMapPackageAtCoordinateListener({ mapPackage, geoCoordinate, resultCode ->
    Timber.i("onGetMapPackageAtCoordinateComplete name = ${mapPackage?.englishTitle}, resultCode = $resultCode")
    val packages = ArrayList<Int>()
    mapPackage?.let {
        packages.add(it.id)
        mapLoader.installMapPackages(packages)
    } ?: Timber.e("No package loaded")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, it was not the **Here SDK**!

Another native library for some reason breaks with a `Signal = SIGUSR2 (signal SIGUSR2)` error and because of that, the whole **Here SDK** stops working!

[image]

The reason for not being able to track the issue was the Java wrapper works fine but **C** part of their code was not working anymore.